# SharePoint 2010 Search not working

Tags: search, search-scope

I have installed and configured SharePoint 2010 to run on the same box as the SQL Server its running from in Windows Server 2008 R2. Everything is working fine except the search. I have uploaded several documents and tagged several items (documents, tasks, announcements etc), however whenever I search the site using the defaul search, i get nothing returned no matter what i search on, I simply get "We did not find any results for [search term]". I know there is setup needed if you wish to use "FAST search", but do I have to do anything to get the standard default search to work?

Comment: Some additional details are needed about how you installed it and which instructions you followed.

Comment: I also have same problem, but mines comes with an error shown below:- Error Internal server error exception: Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation ID: e129228d-cd8b-42ec-bfb1-34ac0f2706e5 Date and Time: 01/07/2010 12:01:22

Comment: when i clicked 'content source' it shows the following error, > The search application 'c4a58254-7afc-4423-bbcf-b0d0a4ae64c2' on
> server SPOINT did not finish loading. View the event logs on the
> affected server for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After installing the system you need to configure your indexing job.

1. Navigate to Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> Search.
2. You will see a link to your Content Sources.  If you edit that it will give you the opportunity to setup a schedule for both Full and Incremental indexing.
3. You can kick off a full crawl, once completed you will have results if everything is configured correctly.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Mike, that worked like a charm. I've been going crazy trying to get that working.

Comment: @Mike, should this search for tags as well? The search works perfectly for finding search terms in file names or content on the website, but doesnt seem to return items by tag, should it?

Comment: All of the social data is stored centrally, not in the site collections or content dbs.  There are a number of timer jobs that aggregate information.  I believe that the "User Profiles - Social Data Maintenance Job" is what handles the tag information.  When all of these jobs run, you should start seeing documents based on tagged value in the search results.

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken.  I thought you could "search" based on your tag term, but you only have the ability to refine a search based on your tags.  The way to access content via the tag name would be to browse the tag cloud.

Comment: I had this exact same problem with Sharepoint 2013. Make sure you hit full crawl.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the content source --> edit. In the **Start Address**. Whether you have entered your site address and use this protocol "sps3".once you done. start the full crawl.

In the search administration-->check for the **scopes**.

Atlast, Check whether SharePoint Foundation/Server Search is in **Started** Status.

Still if you face this problem, Let me know.