# How to allow searching within documents / content?

Tags: search, search-results, metadata, search-content

I would like to see if it is possible via "out of the box" to make the search function return results from within documents in addition to it's normal functionality. Is there any way to achieve this without using 3rd party tools? Can I enable crawling withing documents inside specific document libraries?

This is in regards to SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

Comment: Can you specify what "documents" really mean? Office (doc/docx, ppt/pptx, etc.) or anything more exotic?

Comment: Nothing exotic, just PDF,doc/x, ppt/x, xls/x etc... I would like the search to reference the content of the documents rather than just the metadata keywords and file name.

Comment: In essence, to join my answer to those already expressed here bellow - Enterprise search and even more FAST search should do it already (for Office out-of-the-box), for PDF via the freely available Adobe filter. It must be configure properly though, and ensure that full-crawl has been performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search should do this for recognised file types out of the box.  Note that does not include PDF - you will have to install the PDF iFilter to enable SharePoint to search the content of PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the system you need to configure your indexing job.

1. Navigate to Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> Search.
2. You will see a link to your Content Sources. If you edit that it
   will give you the opportunity to setup a schedule for both Full and
   Incremental indexing.
3. You can kick off a full crawl, once completed you will have results
   if everything is configured correctly.

Source :- [SharePoint 2010 Search not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/sharepoint-2010-search-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Out of Box shareopint will search in the documents like (doc, docx) but to search in PDF Documents you need to install ifilter 
following link shows the installation for ifilter

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82546/How-to-configure-PDF-iFilter-for-SharePoint-Server

After installing ifilter you need to crawl then you will get the result.